# Can you feed power into a breaker of a loadcenter that has no dedicated main breaker, or must you use the main bus lugs?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, nec

For example:

If a loadcenter has main lugs but no dedicated main, can I add a breaker and feed it to light up the bus and then add additional breakers for down-stream circuits?

The idea is to have an easy disconnect at the panel without having to disconnect the breaker at the upstream panel.

If so:

- Can it be a twinned breaker?
- Is there any special labeling required?

Comment: The breaker (and panel?) must be listed for the use, and it requires a hold-down to keep it in place (pretty sure, I'll let one of the usual sparkies definitively answer) I know my listed generator interlock kit includes a hold-down clamp for the backfed breaker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### When you use a circuit breaker to *backfeed*, it must bolt down

You can do that. However when you do, you must apply a bolt-down kit to keep the breaker from rocking out (the way normal breakers will) and leave you holding a hot breaker in your hand.

### In certain subpanels, a local disconnect switch is *mandatory*

(and the cheapest way to do that is use a panel with a main breaker).  I don't know your situation, but an example is an outbuilding, which needs a disconnect switch but it doesn't need to be outside.

In those cases, the breaker will need to be labeled as a disconnect.

### Can you backfeed a double-stuff breaker?

No.

And the very fact you're asking the question shows you have a problem *best avoided*: you are out of spaces / suffering "panel cram" in a panel that is way too small.

See also the need to backfeed a breaker in the first place, which typically is only an issue in <=12 space panels.  Larger panels tend to be "convertible" and have space reserved for a conventional main breaker.

So just junk that too-small subpanel and get a nice big one with loads of spaces. Spaces are cheap when you're buying the panel, and if the last guy hadn't been chintzing out, you would not have a problem today.   Well maybe the person really enjoyed that latté.

Comment: Spot on as usual. 

Comment: Note that the reason *why* you can't backfeed a double-stuff breaker is because the double-stuff breaker is unlikely to accept the retainer kit; in certain situations (QOs come to mind), the double-stuff breakers will likely accept a retainer without issue, and thus have no issue with backfeed

Comment: Good info, needing to bolt-down answers the question.  I was looking at a 12-space panel and wondered about an in-panel disconnect.  Actually we don't need to double-stuff, plenty of room on the 12-space, but just curious.

Comment: The other reason to avoid the double-stuff is that they tend to max. out relatively small. In a quick (big box, so not exhaustive search, but tells you what's commonly available) largest is 50A. Even a small panel can easily use > 50A.